# TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

Tags: python, rect

Ok, so I'm new to Python, and programming in general. But lately I've been making progress and decided to try out the 2D Minecraft tutorial on http://www.usingpython.com - When I go to run the code, which is incomplete because it is at the begining of the tutorial, it gives me this error: TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

The tutorial says that I should see a window with my multi-colored 2D array, but in stead it is a black window that disappears after a few seconds and shows me said error..

Here's what I have, what is wrong with the "rect"? I believe, if im not missing anything, that it's a perfect copy of the code he used to teach.. Frustrated, help? Thanks!!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

#Color link to constants
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BROWN = (153, 76, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#Constants, Same as variables but never changing - they're constant!
DIRT = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL = 3

#Dictionary Linking Resources to colors
colors = {
          DIRT : BROWN,
          GRASS :GREEN,
          WATER : BLUE,
          COAL : BLACK
}

#THE 2D ARRAY
tilemap = [
           [GRASS, COAL, DIRT],
           [WATER, WATER, GRASS],
           [COAL, GRASS, WATER],
           [DIRT, GRASS, COAL],
           [GRASS, WATER, DIRT]
]

#Useful Game Dimensions
TILESIZE = 40
MAPWIDTH = 3
MAPHEIGHT = 5

#Set up the display for PYGAME


pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF =  pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE))
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
         pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colors[tilemap[row][column]],     (column*TILESIZE,TILESIZE,TILESIZE))    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `pygame.Rect` argument here:

```
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colors[tilemap[row][column]],     (column*TILESIZE,TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
```

the 3rd argument has to be a `pygame.Rect` object, you have to build it using 4 integer parameters (there are other possibilities too)

> class Rect(builtins.object)
>    |  Rect(left, top, width, height) -> Rect

That would be syntaxically correct and as quapka noted an argument got lost from the original link so that should be ok:

```
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colors[tilemap[row][column]], pygame.Rect(column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
```

Edit: I just checked and you don't need to pass `pygame.Rect` explicitly as long as you provide 4 parameters:

```
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, colors[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE,TILESIZE))
```

You got the error since you only provided 3 parameters by mistake.

Comment: The exact argument given on the link from OP is `(column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE, TILESIZE,TILESIZE)`. The second argument is missing in OP's code.